# VSCode issues with syntax highlighting for yaml headers in markdown

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting

I have been using VSCode and Pandoc for writing Markdown documents.  VSCode recognizes and highlights some YAML header blocks just fine, but not others.  I noticed the problem on HTML comments in Markdown.

If I use this style of YAML header (closed with dashes) at the very top of the document, VSCode seems to recognize the end of the block, and move back to normal highlighting mode after the close of the block(see screenshot "scratch1.md" document).

```
---
title: Best Article Ever
author: Great Writer
---
```

However, if I use another legal style (closed with ...) which seems to be legal according to the [YAML specification](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html), section 2.2 Structures:

```
---
title: Best Article Ever
author: Great Writer
...
```

VSCode does not seem to see the YAML block as closed, and so highlighting is messed up for the rest of the document (see screenshot below).

This problem (messed up highlighting) does not occur for either style if they are not at the very top of the document.

At this point, I'm not sure where the problem is and how I might go about changing it.  Some pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Is it a problem with my understanding of the YAML syntax?
Is it a problem with the YAML language file in VSCode?
Is it a problem with the markdown language file in VSCode (i.e. problem with the embedded YAML)?
Is it something I have to/can correct with some kind of language extension?

etc.

It isn't hugely important to me, but I have a lot of legacy documents like this and if a correction is reasonably straightforward I'd like to try.

Thanks in advance for any help or explanations.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I work on markdown support for VSCode. Yes, right now you have to use `---` to terminate your frontmatter.

I've opened https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23178 to track support for using `...` as a frontmatter terminator. Feel free to submit a PR for this. I've added some notes on what this would involve: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/23178#issuecomment-289136137

---

**Update**

This should be fixed in VSCode 1.11+

[image: /Users/matb/Desktop/Screen Shot 2017-04-03 at 11.52.58 AM.png]

Here was the fixing PR: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/pull/23195

Comment: Sorry about the delay on this.  Judging by the github issue thread, you've fixed this already.  Thanks a lot for the help on such a minor thing.

Comment: Yep, this should now be fixed in VSCode 1.11+ which should come out later this week. The current insiders builds already have the fix. Please let me know if you run into any problems with this feature

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks a lot for your help on this.

Comment: Hrumph. I’m still getting syntax highlighting errors with the ... terminator in VS Code 1.29.0 for macOS. I’ll file a bug in GitHub.